# How can I change all my links on my Apache site to look for port 8080 instead of 80 after changing my site from 80?

Tags: apache, server, xampp

My local Apache environment, on XAMPP, was set up to listen on port 80.  I now changed it to listen to port 8080. my site now works on port 8080. I have to go to mysite.local:8080 to make it work, which is fine. The only problem is when I click a link it goes to mysite.local/page instead of mysite.local:8080/page and the page does not work. Also, some of my pages that use a log in require me to NOT use 8080 in the url so I have to use mysite.local/admin instead of mysite.local:8080/admin so I am constantaly swithing between adding the port number in the url and taking it away for some other pages. Is there a way where I can make it where I don't have to specify port number on any of the pages. This happened after installing IIS by the way.

My vhost page now looks like the below:

```
<VirtualHost mysite.local:8080>
DocumentRoot "C:\repos\www.mysite.org\web"
ServerName mysite.local
ErrorLog "logs/mysite-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/mysite-access.log" common
<Directory "C:\repos\www.mysite.org\web">
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny 
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that after you changed Apache to listen on 8080 Apache does not even see traffic on :80 (and that's where default HTTP traffic goes).

As you said that you have IIS listening on :80, the only way to solve your problem is to make IIS act as a reverse proxy that would forward all the traffic that should be meant for Apache to Apache.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: [Here](https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis) is tutorial how to do it. Follow the steps and fiddle around to fine-tune your setup.